# CaptainCasa framework: How can we customize DOF Property (DOFPropertyType) alignmnet option

Tags: java, jsp

Do we have option to customize for DOF grid text alignment for specific column?
If not can this be exposed?

Because I have property with datetime format and text is right aligned (by default), but I need text to be left aligned.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option currently. (I would have sworn there is one, to be honest...)

We just added this to DOFPropertyType and added corresponding behavior (DOFPropertyType.set/getGridAlign) and added the rendering to DOFObjectListUI.

Is part of update 20210920 (nest Monday). Thanks for your input!